# Trying to return the minimum value from a lookup table in a complex join

Tags: sql-server, min, lookup-tables

I have a lookup table with job status in order of least to most complete, eg 1=Booking, 2=Pending, 3=InProgress, 4=Invoiced, 5=Finalised, 6=Cancelled etc.

Each session can have dozens of jobs. I want to display a list of Sessions, Locations and the Job with the lowest status, so we know which sessions have jobs that are not yet finalised
eg 30 Jul Brisbane Finalised; 1 Aug Brisbane Booking; 1 Aug Melbourne Invoiced

I've tried the following code which works except that the integer value JobStatusID is displayed not the text from the lookup table. 
If I replace MIN(Jobs.JobStatusID) with MIN (ListJobStatus.JobStatus) then it gives me the first status in alphabetic order instead of the job that needs the most urgent attention.

```
SELECT Sessions.SessionDate, Locations.LocationName, MIN(Jobs.JobStatusID) 
FROM Sessions 
JOIN Locations ON Sessions.LocationID = Locations.ID 
JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.SessionID = Sessions.ID 
JOIN ListJobStatus ON Jobs.JobStatusID = ListJobStatus.ID 
GROUP BY Sessions.SessionDate, Locations.LocationName
```

The output I desire is

```
14 Aug  Brisbane   Invoiced
```

but the output I am getting is

```
14 Aug  Brisbane  4
```

Comment: Can you share your input and expected output?

Comment: What do you get by using `MIN(ListJobStatus.ID)` ?

Comment: Same as MIN(Jobs.JobStatusID). I suspect I need a subquery to return the text value from ListJobStatus table but haven't managed to come up with the correct query yet.